# Redshift - Issue displaying time difference in table stored in table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, timedelta

I am trying to find the time difference between two time stamps and store it in a column. When I check the output in the table, I see the value to be a huge number and not the difference in day/hours. I am using ***amazon redshift*** as the database.

Data_type of time_duration column : *varchar*

Given below is the sample:

```
order_no,order_date,complain_date,time_duration
1001,2018-03-10 04:00:00,2018-03-11 07:00:00,97200000000
```

But I am expecting time_duration column to show 1 day,3 hours

This issue happens when I store the time_duration in a table and then query to view the output.

Could anyone assist.

Thanks.

Comment: What type is `time_duration`?

Comment: @Mureinik, time_duration is also of type varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it following way, it will give hours difference 
`select datediff(hour,order_date,complain_date) as diff_in_hour from your_table ;`

If you want to do it day, do it following way 
`select datediff(day,order_date,complain_date) as diff_in_day from your_table;`

You could use `datediff` function to update your table column `time_duration`.

Refer `Redshift` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any way I could display 1 day 3 hours instead of just 1 day or 27 hours..

Comment: Complex, but you could do it. `select concat( concat(datediff(day,order_date,complain_date),concat(' days,', MOD(datediff(hour,order_date,complain_date),24))),'hrs') from table your_table;`